# How to add variables to the arguments of table1 render.continuous

Tags: r, html-table

Consider the example below: I am trying to add a calculated field `("lower")` to the summary area of the `"Thickness"` but is crashing. I attached a screenshot with the a bluefont. Question: How can I add the formula `**Sum - (SD*1.64)**` to the table? Thanks in advance.

```
library(boot) 
library(table1)

melanoma2 <- melanoma
 
# Factor the basic variables that
# we're interested in
melanoma2$status <- 
  factor(melanoma2$status, 
         levels=c(2,1,3),
         labels=c("Alive", # Reference
                  "Melanoma death", 
                  "Non-melanoma death"))

table1(~ factor(sex) + age + factor(ulcer) + thickness | status, render.continuous=c(.="Sum", .="SD","lower"= "Sum" - ("SD"*1.64)), data=melanoma2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

Could make small edits such as including `round()` to get rid of some of those decimal places.

```
table1(~ factor(sex) + age + factor(ulcer) + thickness | status, 
       render.continuous=function (x) round(c('sum'=sum(x), 'sd'=sd(x),"lower"=sum(x) - sd(x*1.64)),2), data=melanoma2)
```

[image]

Comment: Great!!! Thanks @scott.pilgrim.vs.r I wonder why it takes a function to perform the calculations but it wouldn't work if I only add .=Sum - (SD*1.64). Anyways, Thank you very much.

Comment: When I run your example on my laptop the labels 'sd', and 'lower' are missing. Any idea why?

Comment: ```sd``` and ```lower``` are to be applied to continuous variables like ```thickness``` and ```age``` and not to factors such as ```ulcer``` or ```sex```. Does the table you get when you run it on your laptop look like the picture above?

Comment: No.  On my table, the labels  "sd" and "lower" don't appear below "thickness" or "age" like the table you show. I wonder why. Below "thickness and "age" only the values are showing but not the labels "sd" and "lower"

Comment: Make sure that in your list of functions ```c()``` that you have assigned names to them. Such as ```'sd'=sd(x)```. Note how the label is indicated as a character string ```' '```. Other than that, I don't know what it could be.

Comment: I copied your code directly into Rstudio to ensure I didnt have errors. Not sure why I don't have labels but your graphic does.

Comment: I guess try starting over (clearing your environment) and rerunning your original code form your post (```library(boot)``` to ```melanoma2$status <- ...```) and try again. Somethings amiss and I can't figure it out either.